# Fluent NHibernate Mapping Problem (Override)

Tags: asp.net, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, duplicates

I have tried to make an inheritation mapping. There are two
alternative. One alternative is with `JoinedSubClass` (that is
deprecated and give me a warning) and the other and newer is with
`SubClassMap`.

But I get an error that I have duplicate entity/object mapping. What
could be the problem?

With the `JoinedSubClass` it runs. Here are the Codes of my two Objects
and the `MappingFile` with `JoinedSubClass` which runs, later there are
the code of my mapping file with "SubClassMap" which doesn't run....

Objects:

```
public class Person {

   public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
   public virtual string Vorname { get; set; }
   public virtual string Nachname  { get; set; }
   public virtual string Email { get; set; }
   public virtual Adresse Adresse { get; set; }

   public Person() {
   }
}

public class PersonQuelle : Person, IQuelle {

   public virtual string Beschreibung { get; set; }
   public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<MediaDatei> MediaDateien { get; set; }

   public PersonQuelle() {
       MediaDateien = new List<MediaDatei>();
   }

   public virtual void HinzufuegenMediaDatei(MediaDatei mediaDatei) {
       mediaDatei.PersonQuelle = this;
       MediaDateien.Add(mediaDatei);
   }

public virtual void LoeschenMediaDatei(MediaDatei mediaDatei)
{
       mediaDatei.PersonQuelle = null;
       MediaDateien.Remove(mediaDatei);
   }
}
```

Mapping Files:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person> {

   public PersonMap() {
       Id(x => x.Id);
       Map(x => x.Vorname);
       Map(x => x.Nachname);
       Map(x => x.Email);
       References(x => x.Adresse);

       JoinedSubClass<PersonQuelle>("personQuelle_Id", m => {
           m.Map(c => c.Beschreibung);
           m.References(c => c.Institution);
           m.HasMany(c => c.MediaDateien).Inverse().Cascade.All();
       });

       JoinedSubClass<MMAdminBenutzer>("mmAdminBenutzer_Id", m =>
       {
           m.Map(c => c.Kuerzel);
           m.Map(c => c.Passwort);
           m.Map(c => c.Benutzerrolle);
           m.HasMany(c => c.MediaDateien).Inverse().Cascade.All();
           m.HasMany(c => c.Kategorien).Inverse().Cascade.All();
       });

   }
 }
```

But why it doesn't run when I do that with the same Objects however
with this mapping file??

Mapping File with `SubClassMap`:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person> {

   public PersonMap() {
       Id(x => x.Id);
       Map(x => x.Vorname);
       Map(x => x.Nachname);
       Map(x => x.Email);
       References(x => x.Adresse);
   }
 }

public class PersonQuelleMap : SubclassMap<PersonQuelle>
{
   PersonQuelleMap()
   {
       Map(c => c.Beschreibung);
       References(c => c.Institution);
       HasMany(c => c.MediaDateien).Inverse().Cascade.All();
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell without the error that you get, but I think you are missing a call to `KeyColumn("personQuelle_Id")` in your `SubclassMap`.